# Tor Configuration - Socks5Proxy / Socks4Proxy

Tags: exit-relays, socks, configuration

I'm looking at the [Tor manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en), in particular the `Socks5Proxy` option:

> #### Socks5Proxy *host[:port]*
>
> Tor will make all OR connections through the
> SOCKS 5 proxy at host:port (or host:1080 if port is not specified).

- Can anyone explain this option in more detail?
- Would this option allow an exit node to run over a socks proxy, or is this option only for  users?

Answer (score 1):

In Tor terminology OR connections go from clients and servers. So if a client makes a connection to a relay or two relays have a connection those would be OR connections.

Some institutions use proxies in their network. Usually this are HTTP (and HTTPS) proxies. In some cases another protocol (SOCKS4, SOCKS5 etc.) could also be used for proxying. If you happen to use such a SOCKS proxy in your network, you'll have to set this option.

This option also allows to run an exit node over a SOCKS proxy. However if you do this you should ensure that you don't mess with the traffic of your users.

Comment: "This option also allows to run an exit node over a SOCKS proxy" is true mostly by accident. Your relay will use the Socks5Proxy for outgoing OR connections, but not for outgoing exit streams, and also you still need to be reachable on your advertised ORPort (i.e. you can't use the socks proxy to route incoming connections back to you). So depending on what you mean by "run an exit node over a SOCKS proxy", you will probably be surprised and unhappy with the results.